# Zurb foundation equalizer resize after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation, equalizer

I ran into a problem with Foundation equalizer, I am trying to dynamically readjust div heights with equalizer after I change content with ajax. I searched Foundation documentation, Stack overflow but I found no answer to this problem.

I noticed that it readjusts when I resize the browser, so it is possible, I just want to find out how to trigger it. (I obviously don't want to tell visitors to resize the browser every time they click a link)

edit:
This seems to work, but is that the best solution?

```
$("#media").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "mediaproduction.html"
        })
        .done(function( html ) {
            $( "#main-content" ).html( html );

            $(document).foundation();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

**For Foundation 6 :**

```
Foundation.reInit('equalizer');
```

More info in the doc : http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#adding-plugins-after-page-load

Answer (score 3):

This is what we use on our site to do what you are talking about:

```
$(document).foundation('equalizer','reflow');
```